# Pass vector position in std::for_each

Tags: c++, stl

I have a data structure in sparse compressed column format.

For my given algorithm, I need to iterate over all the values in a "column" of data and do a bunch of stuff.  Currently, it is working nicely using a regular for loop.  The boss wants me to re-code this as a for_each loop for future parallelization.

For those not familiar with sparse compressed column, it use 2 (or 3) vectors to represent the data.  One vector is just a long list of values.  The second vector is the index of where each column starts.

The current version
    // for processing data in column 5
    vector values;
    vector colIndex;
    vector rowIndex;

```
int column = 5;
for(int i = conIndex[5]; i != colIndex[6]; i++){
    value = values[i];
    row = rowIndex[i];
    // do stuff
}
```

The key is that I need to know the **location(as an integer)** in my values column in order to lookup the row position (And a bunch of other stuff I'm not bothering to list here.)

If I use the std::for_each() function, I get the value at the position, not the position.  I need the position itself.

One thought, and clearly not efficient, would be to create a vector of integers the same length as my data.  That way, I could pass an iterator over that dummy vector to the function in for_each and the value passed to my function would be the postion.  However, this seems like the least efficient way.

Any thoughts?

My challenge is that I need to know the *position* in the vector.  for_each takes an iterator and sends the value of that iterator to the function.

Answer (score 4):

Use `boost::counting_iterator<int>`, or implement your own.

Answer (score 1):

@n.m.'s answer is probably the best, but it is possible with only what the standard library provides, though painfully slow I assume:

```
void your_loop_func(const T& val){
    iterator it = values.find(val);
    std::ptrdiff_t index = it - values.begin();
    value = val;
    row = rowIndices[index];
 }
```

And after writing that, I really can only recommend the Boost `counting_iterator` version. ;)